# Showing that $y''+xy'+y=0$ is exact and then finding the general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We can use the condition $P''(x)-Q'(x)+R(x)=0$ to show that $y''+xy'+y=0$ is exact.

I was told that I will need to integrate the equation once then apply the appropriate first order method. I have tried to integrate but got lost with all the variables.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $P''-Q'+R=0$ then the derivative of $Py'+(Q-P')y$ is
$$Py''+P'y'+(Q-P')y'+(Q'-P'')y=Py''+Qy'+Ry\ .$$
So in your case we have
$$y''+xy'+y=\frac{d}{dx}(y'+xy)$$
and integrating the equation gives
$$y'+xy=C\ .$$
You should now be able to recognise this as a familiar type of DE and complete the solution.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

$$y''+xy'+y=0$$
$$xy'+y=(xy)'$$
$$y''+(xy)'=0$$
$$(y'+xy)'=0$$
$$y'+xy=c$$
this is a first order linear ODE easy to solve.